# Xcode does not show merge conflicts in the files when merged using source tree

Tags: xcode, atlassian-sourcetree

Using Source Tree when I tried to merge the changes from Parent branch to current working copy, I see the merge resulting in conflict with some files.

But when I open the conflicted files with Xcode, they do not show any symbols with respect to the conflict occurred. Unable to find the conflicts and also the project doesn't build.

Has anyone faced this weird issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was happening because of parent branch's directory structure got changed by some other sources.